# Extract value in column B when Value in column A is met in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

In R I want to create a calculation when to the value of Column A is met with the second dataset and then it takes the value out of column B from Dataset 1.

```
df1
Patient    Temperature   Heartrate
2894          36.7         80
9801          37.2         78
1110          36.5         98
11650         38.2        102
```

```
df2 
Week 27 
Patient
 3
 4 
1110
9801
```

So now I am trying that when the patient number is met/equal to from the df1. it extracts the temperature or heartrate and I can directly implement it in a formula to use this data. df2 is changing weekly so merging won't be an option I guess. And when it is possible I want to do this in a automatic loop because it is quite the big dataset.

```
Temperature/1.75*Temperature/Heartrate
36.5/1.75*36.5/98
```

Comment: Your second dataset column is `character` or `factor?

Comment: At the moment it is put as character in the second dataset column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` should work OK:

```
with(merge(df2, df1, by = "Patient", all.x = TRUE),
     Temperature / 1.75 * Temperature / Heartrate)
```

You could save the result in df2, too:

```
df2$MyVal <- with(merge(df2, df1, by = "Patient", all.x = TRUE),
     Temperature / 1.75 * Temperature / Heartrate)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help this has helped me to proceed in my project